# Function to combine .csv files to find the mean of a column vs breaking down into smaller commands to find mean

Tags: r

I have 332 .csv files that contain data and I want to find the mean of one particular column for a subset of these combined files.

I tried this and got an answer that is wrong per the answer key:

```
> meanassignment <-function (pollutant, id = 001:332){
>       files <- list.files ("/User/Desktop/Spectdata", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
>       df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=4, nrow=0))
>       for (i in id){
>          data <- read.csv(files[i])
>          dat <- rbind.data.frame (df2,data)
>            }
>        mean(dat[[pollutant]], na.rm = TRUE)  
>  }
```

`

I tried to break it down into smaller section and I am getting the correct answer.

```
>   x <- read.csv("070.csv", header = TRUE)
>   y <- read.csv("071.csv", header = TRUE)
>   a <-rbind.data.frame(x,y)
>   z<-read.csv("072", header= TRUE)
>   z <- read.csv("072.csv", header = TRUE)
>   b <- rbind.data.frame(a,z)
>   mean(b$nitrate, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Can anyone please let me what i am doing wrong in the first section of the meanassignment function? Thank you!

Comment: First you should try to make your code snippet reproducible. As it stands there are many things wrong with it, and it is not clear if this is due to code that you are not providing or just the error. For example, there is no variable "directory" and it is unclear why this whole code is inside a function.

Comment: "Scope breach". You must believe that the reference to `directory` from inside the function will happily find the value of it in your working environment. While this is true, this is bad practice from a reproducibility (and programming) viewpoint: the function should always behave the same given the same arguments, but this function relies on something outside of its arguments. There are few times in R when a function should safely rely on variables outside of its arguments (fewer times where *side-effect* is justified, though that's not happening here).